# Why does the core search module not index node titles?

Tags: 7, search

The search results only show terms in the body if that. Take the example of a product site. There is a product called Funkywidget with a description that has Funckywidget written twice in it. However, the core search module does not show any results for Funkywidget. It has a record in the search_index table but doesn't show when typed into the search form.

What is the best way to enable people to find a Funkywidget?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> There is a product called Funkywidget

If the *title* of the node is "Funkywidget" it's searchable by that term. If you want to incorporate search terms that aren't in the node's fields, you should look at more complex search solutions like Apache Solr.

See here: http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.module/function/_node_index_node/6 
The title is added to the search string that's going in the db.

`$text = '<h1>' . check_plain($node->title) . '</h1>' . $node->body;`

Comment: The core search module absolutely does not make the terms in the title field searchable.

Comment: See code above, it should be in there.

Comment: This is a bug in the Workbench Moderation module.

Comment: I have had that problem with title too. Is there a workaround or patch for the Workbench Moderation bug?